# WooCommerce REST API - GET Orders since Order ID

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using the [WooCommerce REST API](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/wp-api-v2.html#list-all-orders) to download Orders into our internal CRM database. We're currently doing this by requesting all Orders between 2 date ranges, e.g.

`wp-json/wc/v2/orders?after=2018-05-08T00:00:00Z&before=2018-05-14T23:59:59Z&page=1&orderby=id&order=asc`

and this is working well. We were wondering if it's possible to change this to just request all new orders since the last Order ID that we downloaded. For example if the last Order ID we downloaded was `2450` we would like to make a request to get all new Orders after 2450. I've been reading the docs for the parameters to list all Orders but not sure if this is actually possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this is not currently possible. Hopefully a future update to the API will allow this.